# Logic Apps returns Error 404 for Get File Content while Looping in Sharepoint's parent folder

Tags: azure-logic-apps

when I run Get File Content for the parent folder it retuns the following error

[image]

If I'm doing this for the last folder placed in this parent folder it is OK.

Not working:

[image]

Working:

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you make sure that whatever file you are trying to retrieve is present in that parent folder?

Comment: There are different excels present in main and child folders, also there are empty child folders

Comment: So are you trying to retrieve the one in the parent? also, make sure you are mentioning its extension of the excel file that you are retrieving.

Comment: I'm able to retrieve from the child folder, from the main I can't, yes I'm filtering on .xlsx the filter works i've tested for the working child folder

Comment: In general, 404 occurs when there are no files present in that particular folder. Can you able to view the required files(i.e., .xlsx files) through the `List folder2` action?

Comment: yes there are some empty child folders is it possible to filter them out from the loop, I can view the files in output from List folder2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get file Content` works only for file types but not folders and `List Folder` gives what all the folders that are present in the path but not the files in the nested folders. If you are trying to get the list of all files in all the folders in your share point then instead of using `List Folder`, you can use `Get files (properties only)` as it lists all the folders and files present in the path and looping through its "value" filtering "Is folder" gives us desired results. `Is Folder` checks if it's a 3file or a folder. Here is my logic app which filters all the files in the sharepoint using `Condition` connector and `Is Folder` property.

[image]